# Create limited super admin on multisite (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, multisite

Is it possible to create a user on a multisite that has access to all the sites in the network, but has limited permissions to for example install plugins and view/edit certain settings? The only thing I want this user to be able to do is to jump in between sites and be able to edit the content of these, without having to log in and out with different accounts on each of the sites.

The most optimal solution would be if I could create a new user role based on the super admin role, and then deactivate permissions from there. But from what I see in the admin interface of the network, I seem to only be able to give a user the super admin role and no other role, except for if I create a user on any of the specific "sub sites" in the network.

Any ideas for how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I totally misunderstood how this works. I just figured out that I have to do the following:

1. Create a user on the network. From what I understand, I should not assign the Super Admin role to this user if I don't want the user to have access to the network settings.
2. Go to **Users** > **Add New** on the sites where I want this user to have access and enter the email or username of the user in the input field under **Add Existing User**.
3. Choose the **Role** that this user should have on the specific site.
4. Click **Add Existing User**

The user can now login to either one of the sites where the user was added and can switch in between the sites in the admin bar, without having access to the network admin area.

For now I selected the Editor role for this user to limit access to plugins and other settings that only the admin should have access to. If I want to modify the capabilities of the user I could either do it manually or just install a plugin like [User Role Editor](https://www.role-editor.com/) to do this.